# Visual Studio 2013 Integration project errors

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I created a visual studio 2013 integration project to copy data from an MS ACCESS database to a remote SQL Server (~13,000 records).  The first time I ran it, it almost finished with (~12,000) with the following errors:

> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An
> OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
> available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"
> Hresult: 0x80004005   Description: "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead
> (recv()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.   The "OLE DB
> Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error
> code 0xC020907B occurred,  and the error row disposition on "OLE DB
> Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]"  specifies failure on
> error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component.   There may be error messages posted before this with more
> information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error
> Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.    The ProcessInput method on component
> "OLE DB Destination" (2)   failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
> processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (15).   The identified
> component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
> specific to the component,   but the error is fatal and will cause the
> Data Flow task to stop running.    There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information about the failure.

I ran the test a second and 3rd time, but each time it seem to fail only transferring less than 2000 records.

What could be the problem?  Is this a network issues, as it seems all my mappings are correct.

Comment: `General network error. Check your network documentation.".`. Yep looks like a network issue...

Answer (score 0):

This was a user error.  My visual studio was not showing the count transferred.  Something with the themes.  I decided to go into sql server and run a query to check what was been transferred.  This was the culprit.  It broke each time I ran it!  So bad idea to be messing with sql server when running SSIS.